# Write a program to print all input lines that are longer than 80 characters

Tags: beginner, c

Like many posts before, I'm going through `The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition, by Kernighan and Ritchie`.

I am very new to the `c` programming language. While I have a somewhat decent understanding of programming basics, I'm most looking forward to learning about memory management in `c`.

Anyway, I'm looking for feedback on my latest exercise solution from the book.

`Exercise 1-17. Write a program to print all input lines that are longer than 80 characters.`

My initial solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MINCHARS 80
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getLine(char line[], int size);

int main() {
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char minCharsLine[MAXLINE][MAXLINE];
    int lineCharCount[MAXLINE];
    int c;
    int len;
    int lineCount;
    len = 0;
    lineCount = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        line[len] = c;
        len++;
        if (len > MINCHARS) {
            if (c == '\n') {
                lineCount++;
                strcpy(minCharsLine[lineCount], line);
                lineCharCount[lineCount] = len;
                len = 0;
            }
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            len = 0;
        }
    }
    if (lineCount > 0 ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lineCount + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lineCharCount[i]; j++) {
                printf("%c", minCharsLine[i][j]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("No lines over 80 characters\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: "all input lines that are longer than 80 characters" --> does that 80 include the potential `'\n'`?

Comment: _"I'm most looking forward to learning about memory management in c."_ Ah, a fellow programming-masochist I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Nice layout/formatting**

Object names are reasonable.

**Saving more than about 80 characters is not needed**

Once the "80" line length is reach, print the first 80 characters and then the rest of incoming characters until end-of-line/end-of-file.

`char minCharsLine[MAXLINE][MAXLINE]`, `int lineCharCount[MAXLINE]` not needed.

**Good that code saved the return value of `getchar()` in an `int`**

`getchar()` returns 257 different values<sup>*1</sup>.  Saving in a `char` can lose information.

**Function signature**

For this student exercise, `int getLine(char line[], int size);` is OK - but curiously **never defined**?

In C, array indexes can exceed `INT_MAX`.  The *unsigned* type `size_t` is size to accommodate all array indexing and object sizing.   Consider

```
size_t getLine(char line[], size_t size); 
// or  
size_t getLine(size_t size, char line[]);
```

The first form is more common.
Advanced: The 2nd has an advantage when coded as

```
size_t getLine(size_t size, char line[size]);
```

Yet for various portability concerns, this needs to wait until C2x.

**Must the *last* line contain a `'\n'`?**

Your design choice.

Best to be clear about what code does if it received an `EOF` following a non-`'\n'`. That is, the last *line* did not end with a `'\n'`.

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. C17dr § 7.21.2 2

**`MAXLINE` is not necessarily the same as `LINECOUNT_N`**

Better as:

```
// char minCharsLine[MAXLINE][MAXLINE];

#define LINECOUNT_N 1024
char minCharsLine[LINECOUNT_N][MAXLINE];
```

**`MAXLINE` versus alternates**

Many off-by-one errors stem from not being clear.
`MAXLINE` sounds like the maximum returned `strlen(line)`.  To achieve that length, the array size needed is `MAXLINE + 1`.
Perhaps:

```
#define MAXLINE 80
#define LINE_SIZE (MAXLINE + 1)
char line[LINE_SIZE];

// or 

#define MAXLINE 80
char line[MAXLINE + 1];
```

**Line counts can be large**

Code performs `minCharsLine[lineCount]` without ever checking if `lineCount` is too high.  Better to exit with an error message than go on.

The line count of a file is not limited to `INT_MAX`.  I'd use `unsigned long` or `uintmax_t` for the line count.  Of course even that is not the upper bound, just a safer bet.

**Simplification**

OP's code is OK and does handle the unexpected reading of *null characters* and "prints" them with:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < lineCharCount[i]; j++) {
            printf("%c", minCharsLine[i][j]);
        }
```

Simplier to use:

```
        fwrite(minCharsLine[i], lineCharCount[i], 1, stdout);
```

If code does not need to support reading *null characters*, make sure `minCharsLine[i]` is 1 wider, append a *null character* to `minCharsLine[i]`,and use the below:

```
        fputs(minCharsLine[i], stdout);
```

**Simplify??**

Along time ago `printf("%c", minCharsLine[i][j])` was considered inefficient versus the simpler `putchar(minCharsLine[i][j])`.  That still applies to some compilers today, yet good compilers are *smart* and will emit efficient code either way.

Using `putchar(minCharsLine[i][j])` is typically *better*, yet for such linear optimization cases as this over that, do consider clarity of code and let the compiler cope with optimizations.

**`fgets()`**

`fgets()` is mostly a drop in replacement for this exercise, yet it has functional difference in special cases.

---

<sup>*1</sup> `EOF` and [0...`UCHAR_MAX`].  This may be more than 257 different values when `UCHAR_MAX` is more than 255.

Comment: Pedantry: s/257/UCHAR_MAX + 2/

Comment: @TobySpeight, answer amended. The pedantry gets uglier when `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, (e.g. all integer types are 64-bit).  Such machines oblige code like `int ch; fclear(stdin); while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && (!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin))) { ... }`.   In that case, `UCHAR_MAX + 1` different values.

Comment: Oh that's ugly - I hope I don't have to deal with one of those...

Comment: @TobySpeight For _getline_ code, I have used `while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && !IS_TRUE_EOF(ch, stdin)) {` and `#if INT_MAX <= UCHAR_MAX #define IS_TRUE_EOF(ch, inf) ((ch)==EOF) #else #define IS_TRUE_EOF(ch, inf) (((ch)==EOF)) && (iseof(inf) || iserror(inf))) #endif` to distribute the ugly.  Its the  prior `fclear(stdin);` I find especially troubling - I'd like to determine if `EOF` occurred due to an input error that [just happened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53274876/2410359).